# Android ViewPager inside a ScrollView isnt scrolling

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have a ViewPager linked with a TabLayout and they are both inside a ScrollView the ViewPager has a PagerAdapter with views added at runtime but the problem is that the ScrollView doesn't scroll vertically, I tried using different height for the ViewPager and the TabLayout but it didn't work I checked out a bunch on question on the subject but none of the recommendations worked for me the ViewPager has a list of views but I dont want to use a Recycler view or a ListView because I want the whole screen to scroll and not just the ViewPager.

here's the xml for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/dark_gray"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/character_info_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The xml layout for the list items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    tools:src="@color/dark_gray"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_name_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="18dp"
    android:paddingBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    tools:text="Item Name goes here"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the ViewPager's PagerAdapter (where I add the views at runtime)

```
 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
    {
        LinearLayout itemsContainer = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        itemsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0; i < ProfileInfoItems.getSize(position); i++)
        {
            LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_info_view, container, false);
            TextView itemTitle = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name_text_view);
            ImageView itemIcon = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);

            itemTitle.setText(ProfileInfoItems.getName(position, i));
            itemIcon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ProfileInfoItems.getIcon(position, i)));

            itemsContainer.addView(item, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        itemsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        container.addView(itemsContainer);
        return itemsContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object)
    {
        return view == object;
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
    {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return TAB_LABELS.length;
    }

}
```

[A screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTkoc.png)

Thanking you all in advance for your time and effort :)

Comment: Why make `ScrollView` the parent layout ?

Comment: `ScrollView`there is pointless. Shouldn't the Fragment that's added to the `ViewPager` contain a `ListView` and than fill that one up with those items, and it'll be scrollable.

Comment: I know, but I want the WHOLE page to scroll down along with the ImageView I plan to put above the AppBarLayout late.